# How to change the url of webpage using javascript

Tags: javascript

I want to write javascript code for any webpage such that if it contains some required text or value then change it's `url` or add something to it's `url` and again load the webpage with the updated `url`.

for example: open `www.google.co.in`

Now I will check that if the `div` with `class` `logo-subtext` contains `India` like this

`<div class="logo-subtext">India</div>`

then change the url to `www.google.com` and reload the page.

I want to add this to my tamper monkey.

In India many websites are blocked. I want to open those websites by using `hidingnet.com`.

So if website is blocked then we are getting the following message:

`*“This website/url has been blocked under instructions of the Competent Government Authority or in compliance to the orders of Hon’ble Court.”*`

So for example: this page is blocked or `url`

`http://bleacherreport.com/articles/2605069-three-targets-for-tottenham-hotspur-to-hit-in-2016?`

but I can open it by applying `hidingnet.com` in following way:

`http://bleacherreport.com.hidingnet.com/articles/2605069-three-targets-for-tottenham-hotspur-to-hit-in-2016?`

So I need help for the above.

Comment: Have you tried anything so far? What you are trying to do sounds like a browser extension.... is that correct?

Comment: In JavaScript you can change url using `window.location = 'http://www.google.com'`. What is your scope, where do you want to use it ?

Comment: Yeah - need some more information or see what you've tried so far, but `window.location` as stated above will definitely get you going in the right direction. If you want to change the URL without refreshing or redirecting, you can check out `history.pushState()` and the other `history.` library functions.